# How to use max function in this query with sum after joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

```
SELECT  s.seg_name, p.category,  SUM(t.item_qty * t.item_price) revenue
FROM segments s 
JOIN transactions t 
ON s.cust_id = t.cust_id
JOIN products p 
ON p.prod_id = t.prod_id
WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y' 
GROUP BY s.seg_name, p.category
```

I want to use the max function or something else to select the highest revenue based on the given group columns in the query posted

Comment: Please show us your current results, and your desired results. There is more than one way to interpret your question.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show what relevant parts you are able to do & explain about how you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to understand your question.

If you want to top row in the resultset, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT  s.seg_name, p.category,  SUM(t.item_qty * t.item_price) revenue
FROM segments s 
JOIN transactions t  ON s.cust_id = t.cust_id
JOIN products p  ON p.prod_id = t.prod_id
WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y' 
GROUP BY s.seg_name, p.category
ORDER BY revenue DESC
LIMIT 1
```

On the other hand, if you want to keep all rows and add one column that show the top revenue over the whole dataset, then you can use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0 only):

```
SELECT  
    s.seg_name, 
    p.category,  
    SUM(t.item_qty * t.item_price) revenue,
    MAX(SUM(t.item_qty * t.item_price)) OVER() max_revenue
FROM segments s 
JOIN transactions t  ON s.cust_id = t.cust_id
JOIN products p  ON p.prod_id = t.prod_id
WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y' 
GROUP BY s.seg_name, p.category
```